# In Word, is there a way to re-enable the autosave files list(see them again), after once I said "no "?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

During months, when I opened my Word 2016, it used to show a long list of old  unsave autosaved  files, whih I never had time to review  and save.
Once When closing Word, to the question whether I want to see the autosaved files later, by error, I clicked on "no". And they all disappeared. Now when I open Word it no longer shows the list of my old unsaved files Is there a way to revert this and to see them again?